# Use Web.Config variables from database & access to all the pages in the application

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, web-config, session-variables

Instead of saving my database password & all other variables we are saving in the web.config , I want to use it & access from the database table.

Meaning I want to access all the variables from the tables at the time of login.

**I want to achieve this because it will give ease of configuration & i do not have to restart the application whenever when config will change & also do not want to show web.config to users**

Currently I am storing all the variables data in to the session & accessing it into all the application.

but i get to know that when user increases session degrade the performance of the application.

So , need a suggestion what would be the best way to access table data & access in all the pages of application wherever we want them.

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="CnSQL" value="XXXXXXXXX"/>
    <add key="IsReadingShown" value="XXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <add key="WTAFunction" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <add key="ProjectName" value="XXXXXXX"/>
</appSettings>
```

Previously I was using above config file & was accessing the parameter in all the application.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Meaning I want to access all the variables from the tables at the time of login* What does it mean?

Comment: It means , we store all the configurable variable which can be editable in the Web.Config fie. Now I want to access all the parameter from the Database  table.

Comment: So, you mean you want that in SQL query isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I want to store it into the table of SQL & want to access it into the dot net application & want to use across all the pages of application

Comment: Please add your web config file to the question.

Comment: Just read your app setting from code and pass it to your sql query.